# OpenCV not capturing the desired rectangles and text

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am trying to create rectangle boxes to capture the product item and price as noted here. I have drawn the boxes below to indicate what I am trying to achieve. [image: Want].
[image: Sample]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread('flyers/longos-flyer-january-20-to-261-1.jpg', 1)

# Preprocess
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Grayscale
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (7,7),0)
# imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlur,100,100)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(imgBlur, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
#
thresh = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (11, 11))

connected = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) #dilation followed by erosion

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print('Number of contours' + str(len(contours)))
roi_arr = []
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    if area > 8000:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        padding = 0
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y + padding), (x + w, y + h +padding), (0,255,0), 3)
        roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_arr.append(roi)

flyer_str = []
for i in roi_arr:
    i_gray = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    i_gray = cv2.resize(i_gray, None, fx=2, fy=2)
    string = pytesseract.image_to_string(i_gray)

    flyer_str.append(string)


print(flyer_str)
print(len(flyer_str))

cv2.imwrite("Sample.png", img)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Image Gray', imgGray)
cv2.imshow('Image Blur', imgBlur)
# cv2.imshow('Image Canny', imgCanny)
cv2.imshow('Image Result', connected)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Any help or insights would be appreciated. For reference, here is the original photo (https://flyers.smartcanucks.ca/canada/longos-flyer-january-20-to-261)

Comment: Threshold on red using cv2.inRange(). The red box will become white  and some other red areas will become white and the rest black. Then get contours and get the largest one. Contours work on white areas, not black ones.

Comment: This would remove those red boxes but what about capturing the lines that somewhat seperate the products as seen on the flyer?